# SXA JSON Results don't read from custom index

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I've created custom index instead of **"sitecore_sxa_web_index"**, the Search Results component fetch data from the custom index and works fine, but the JSON Results still fetch data from the OOB index, I tried adding **itemId** parameter to the JSON Results request, I tried also adding the location of the content in the search scope, but still the issue exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine on the latest version. Both Search Results and JSON Results are using custom index (both of them are using `IndexResolver` to get proper index).

If this doesn't work on an older version you will need to request a hotfix. Please contact Sitecore support.